# how to calculate cumulative distribution function inverted exponential in this pic

Tags: probability-distributions, inverse, exponential-distribution

how to calculate cumulative distribution function inverted exponential in this pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rswu.png)

Comment: What have you attempted ?

Comment: There is mistake in (1).$P\left(\frac{1}{X}\leq x\right)=P\left(X\geq\frac{1}{x}\right)=e^{-\frac{\theta}{x}}$ for positive $x$. That might be the source of the confusion of the OP.